Limit only shipping states (provinces) but not billing states in WooCommerce
I have the following code which limits the provinces to Valencia (Spain) only, in WooCommerce:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'tl45r_custom_woocommerce_states' );

function tl45r_custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

    // Only show specific provinces (Madrid - MD and Barcelona - B) for Spain (ES)
    $states['ES'] = array(
        //'MD' => __( 'Madrid', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'B'  => __( 'Barcelona', 'woocommerce' ),
        'V'  => __( 'Valencia', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $states;
}

However, I want this limitation only be applied to the shipping field but not the billing field.
How can I do this?

To apply restriction only to shipping states, first you need to choose in WooCommerce "General" Settings, on Shipping location(s) the "Ship to specific countries only" option and in Ship to specific countries field, type "Spain" option (in your case), like:

Then replace woocommerce_states with woocommerce_countries_shipping_country_states filter hook, like:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_shipping_country_states', 'customized_shipping_country_states' );
function customized_shipping_country_states( $states ) {
    // Only show specific provinces (Madrid - MD and Barcelona - B) for Spain (ES)
    $states['ES'] = array(
        //'MD' => __( 'Madrid', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'B'  => __( 'Barcelona', 'woocommerce' ),
        'V'  => __( 'Valencia', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $states;
}

Now in checkout, only "Valencia" shipping state is available for Spain.
This is what I get on Classic checkout (shortcode):

Note that it doesn't work for instance in Checkout Blocks.

I thought it's doing the trick, but for some reason it's not working on my live site. Please see this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qtr0rRZL3nCchUFjrTbGUMt2UIkVc9WN/view?usp=drivesdk What am I missing here?

Maybe because you are using Checkout Blocks, and it seems that this filter hook doesn't work with it… It works perfectly with classic checkout (I added a screenshot in my answer). I don't see any other related hook in WC_Countries class. So this could be a bug related to Checkout Blocks…

For sure, checkout blocks are smarter and look nicer, but they allow only very few customizations that require a much more complex and advanced coding. You could try to open an issue in WooCommerce GitHub.

You're right, it has to do something with blocks, thanks for the note!

Bug report: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/51749

Saw it, thanks! :-)

I don't know why, but this code works with checkout blocks as well: https://old.reddit.com/r/woocommerce/comments/1fr9371/limit_shipping_province_but_not_billing_province/lpfmn2j/

@orschiro But this code alters also the billing state, what you want to avoid, as woocommerce_states hook alter both billing and shipping state fields.
